# The requested resource [/authenticateTheUser] is not available

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to build spring based authentication system  using spring security. I have downloaded all jar files and linked with the project.I am using eclipse as a ide.The error I am getting is this **The requested resource [/authenticateTheUser] is not available** where I if add this spring will automatically add this but it is showing like this.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.UserBuilder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class DemoSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        // add our users for in memory authentication
        
        UserBuilder users = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder();
        
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser(users.username("john").password("test123").roles("EMPLOYEE"))
            .withUser(users.username("mary").password("test123").roles("MANAGER"))
            .withUser(users.username("susan").password("test123").roles("ADMIN"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/showMyLoginPage")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")
                .permitAll()
            .and().logout().permitAll();
        
    }
        
}
```

this is the config file I have the authenticate user but it is not working

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>  
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    
    <title>Login Page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
    <!-- Reference Bootstrap files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
         href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div>
        
        <div id="loginbox" style="margin-top: 50px;"
            class="mainbox col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2">
            
            <div class="panel panel-info">

                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-title">Sign In</div>
                </div>

                <div style="padding-top: 30px" class="panel-body">

                    <!-- Login Form -->
                    <form:form action="${pageContent.request.cotextPath}/authenticateTheUser" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">

                        <!-- Place for messages: error, alert etc ... -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-15">
                                <div>
                                    <c:if test="${param.error!= null}">
                                        <div class="alert alert-danger col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10">
                                            Invalid username and password.
                                        </div>

                                    </c:if>
                                    <!--                    
                                    
                                    -->
                                    
                                    <!-- Check for logout -->
                                    
                                    <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
                                                
                                        <div class="alert alert-success col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10">
                                                You have been logged out.
                                        </div>
                                    
                                    </c:if>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- User name -->
                        <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span> 
                            
                            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" class="form-control">
                        </div>

                        <!-- Password -->
                        <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span> 
                            
                            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" class="form-control" >
                        </div>

                        <!-- Login/Submit Button -->
                        <div style="margin-top: 10px" class="form-group">                       
                            <div class="col-sm-6 controls">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </form:form>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the jsp file the frontend portion is here

This is the error I am getting

[image]

Comment: `${pageContent.request.cotextPath}` is probably not what you meant. (For that matter, replace JSP with Thymeleaf and just use `@{/authenticate}`.)